# If Statement To Remove Leading http://www. Off Of URL

Tags: php, if-statement

I'm somewhat new to PHP, so this will probably sound stupid, but how you best rewrite the below code to remove the leading http:// and/or www. off of a url if they are present?

```
function jt_cmb_validate_text_url( $new ) {
    if ( '' == $new ) { return; }

    if ( !preg_match('/http:\/\//', $new) ) {
        $new = 'http://' . $new;
    }

    return $new;
}
```

As you can see, the code adds the leading http:// to the url if it isn't already present, but as I'm trying to remove both the http:// and www. 
Would you go with four if statements (one if none are present, one each if only a single thing is present and another for when both are present)?

Any help would be much appreciated. :)

Comment: If you want to remove it, why are you adding it...?

Comment: No, I want to rewrite the above code using the same parameters to remove the http:// and/or www. instead of adding http://

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To ensure that you don't remove any more than you need to (for instance, there could be a full URL in the query string you don't want to remove), you should use a regex:

```
$new = preg_replace("(^(?:https?://)?(?:www\.)?)","",$old);
```

Answer (score 1):

[str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) — Replace all occurrences of the search string with the replacement string

```
str_replace ("http://" , "", $url )
str_replace ("www." , "", $url )
```

General syntax

```
mixed str_replace ( mixed $search , mixed $replace , mixed $subject [, int &$count ] )
```

**count** - If passed, this will be set to the number of replacements performed.

Comment: But what if there is a URL in the query string? Example: `http://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/www.facebook.com`

Comment: @Kolink That's not a valid URL